# Correct structure for custom domain feature for SAAS users

Tags: saas, wildcard-subdomain

I am building a Saas platform (lets assume domain is www.saas.com) where user have unique subdomains such as user1.saas.com, user2.saas.com etc. And give them a feature to add their own custom domain.

To add custom domain, users define cname for app.saas.com and A record for public id in of my app.

Everything is working fine if cname and A record is defined correctly by users. But i have two concers about this:

1. To host my app, i used cloudways and select digital ocean servers. But if i want to move from Digital Ocean to AWS at some point, then public ip is going to change. So custom domains wont work until users change their A record.I wonder if is there a better way to give custom domain feature to user instead of adding A record? (I am not sure if cname and a record is the correct way for this feature)
2. Let's assume user1 is defined own domain for user1.saas.com. When i go to user1.saas.com, it is also working. I think, i should redirect this url to custom domain if it is defined. I wonder if this is a correct way?

Thanks in advance
Anil

Comment: 1. `CNAME` is [usually](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain)  [used](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=en), but it does come with [some limitations](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain) 2. I personally don't think you should redirect, unless it has some SEO positive consequences (which is beyond my knowledge).

Comment: Hi Dusan, thank you. I checked support.google topic and it looks like they can manage this custom domain feature by just adding a CNAME record. It looks like A Record is not necessary. But when i didn't add A Record, custom domain didn't work, should i make a configuration at my apache, do you know anything about it?

Comment: I know something about it, but you should probably ask a new question and provide exact example, with DNS configuration and apache configuration, and then we can figure out why it is not working as expected